# SwiftUI show collection of images

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to show a grid of images similar to `UICollectionView` like this:

[image]

With each color representing an image.

When I do the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<8) { i in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { j in
                        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Image("image")
                                .background(Color.random)
                                .clipped()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                        .background(Color.random)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get one image which is not bound by its frame and therefore fills the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a frame and resizable modifier to you image.

```
Image("image")
 .resizable()
 .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
```

Full example

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<8) { i in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { j in
                        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Image("image")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this [image]