# Display correct rows and colums based on data response SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to show a set of images that are returned from the backend similar to the colors displayed here [SwiftUI show collection of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056237/swiftui-show-collection-of-images)

In the ViewModel I have

```
@Published var numberOfRows = 0
@Published var numberOfCols = 0

init() {
    numberOfRows = 3
    numberOfCols = 3
}
```

The problem comes from displaying the images dynamically depending on what I get back from the server.

In my body I have

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        ForEach(0..<viewModel.numberOfRows) { i in
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<viewModel.numberOfCols) { j in
                    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                        AsyncImage(url: url) {
                            Text("Loading ...")
                        }.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                    .background(Color.random)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The main thing is this

```
ForEach(0..<viewModel.numberOfRows) { i in
```

But here I get a warning that

> Non-constant range: argument must be an integer literal

when I hard code a 3 in there then it gets displayed correctly but using the values from the view model nothing is displayed

Comment: Look into the provided grids

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` needs unique identifiers, just add

```
ForEach(0..<viewModel.numberOfRows, id: \.self)
```

and

```
ForEach(0..<viewModel.numberOfCols, id: \.self)
```